# Why does Microsoft suggest we use properties for static data types, rather than static fields?

Tags: c#, .net-core, properties, field

Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/d53b55ey%28v%3Dvs.71%29) still relevant?

> It is recommended that you use static properties instead of public static fields whenever possible.

If so, why?

**EDIT:** I don't think it's an opinion based-question when we are asking for clarification on **why** Microsoft's coding style is defined the way it is.

Comment: Functional abstraction

Comment: public fields are always considered bad style, not only if they are static.

Comment: Properties allow you to change things over time, like add validation to a property setter to validate the value, or mutate state etc. You can't do things like that with fields, and changing a field to a property at a later date would be a binary-breaking change.

Comment: Another reason to avoid static fields *and* properties is testability - devs are always tempted to use them leading to tests that fail in unexpected ways when run in parallel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the linked article, there is another link, [Field Usage Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/ta31s3bc%28v%3dvs.71%29), containing this explanation:

> Do not use instance fields that are public or protected (Public or Protected in Visual Basic). If you avoid exposing fields directly to the developer, classes can be versioned more easily because a field cannot be changed to a property while maintaining binary compatibility.

That applies to static fields as well as to non-static/instance fields. It means that you can later change how the field backing a property maybe set or get without breaking dependencies.
If you released the class with a public field, you can never change this without troubling developers already accessing that field.

Comment: "That applies to static fields as well as to non-static/instance fields." I disagree. If it would apply to static fields as well then it wouldn't have the `instance` word there. In fact, the same document states "Use public static read-only fields for predefined object instances. If there are predefined instances of an object, declare them as public static read-only fields of the object itself."

Comment: @ZoharPeled I think "predefined object instances" are a special use case (like `IntPtr.Zero` etc).. You use static **readonly** fields for that because you really don't intend to ever change setters or getters for them, they are more like constants than fields (but need to be fields because they are not compile-time constant).

Comment: I tend to agree with that, however that is still a valid usage of static fields (be it readonly) - and therefor the "do not use instance fields" does not apply to static fields...

Comment: @ZoharPeled I actually wrote this question exactly due to that - I had a public readonly static field, and was really confused if I need to explicitly make it private, or leave it like that.

Comment: @ZoharPeled in the end it's a "guide-line", not a rule that has to be obeyed 100% of the time.